# How to integrate brighttalk webcast to my website? How can I get the Feed of Brithtalk Videos?

Tags: php, web-services, youtube

I have account on https://www.brighttalk.com/
This site will allow us to Play any Webcast.

I would like to show / integrate the Webcast from www.brighttalk.com to my website page.

But, I have not found any API or Code to integrate the video webcast to my website.

Example Webcast
https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/6833/79693

anyone has idea how to do above?

Extra Question:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://www.brighttalk.com/clients/js/embed/embed.js">
</script>

<object class="BrightTALKEmbed" width="705" height="660">
    <param name="player" value="channel_player"/>
    <param name="domain" value="http://www.brighttalk.com"/>
    <param name="channelid" value="8025"/>
    <param name="communicationid" value="87263"/>
    <param name="autoStart" value="false"/>
    <param name="theme" value=""/>
</object>
```

This is sample Code I have and It is working now.
Other question is that How can i get all the Videos/Seminar list/RSS/FEED to get all and show in my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made research and I got the answer

```
http://www.brighttalk.com/channel/{CHANNEL_ID}/feed
```

This will return the XML format of feed.
Now, We just need to parse the XML and show the video.

e.g.

```
http://www.brighttalk.com/channel/43/feed
```

Comment: Channel feeds do not contain the webcast assets - they provide overview details of each webinar that is published in the specified channel.

Answer (score 3):

see on right side of the website a green <> embed button... click on it and copy the code on your site...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use the javascript embed code that is provided from the site - the player code is rapidly changing at the moment - as we continue to improve our mobile support.

Including the JS embed ensures that you will always get the latest player from us.

Comment: correct but using the data we can embed player code with given URL data.

Comment: Given our players will be getting major changes in the coming 12 months I would discourage you from attempting to reverse engineer them.

Comment: So as per you opinion what is the better for me in my Drupal 7.x Site to get all the data?

**How can I get the Feed of Brithtalk Videos?**

Comment: We do have a Drupal Module that provides feeds etc. https://drupal.org/project/feeds_brighttalk  I am very keen to hear any feedback about it.

Comment: I will try your given module with my site.
If I use this module will it provide to theme/format listing of videos?

Comment: It links to our widgets for the embeds - they support some limited theming - our design point is to make the chrome as minimal as possible going forward so that there is not much to offend / worry about.